# Is it possible read the data from company file with out opening Quick book software?

Tags: c#, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Is it possible get the data with out opening the company file from QB.

I have below scenario :

In my client system has only  QuickBooks Database file( does n't have QuickBook s/w).
Is it possible to get the data from Company database.

I have succeeded to get the data if QB is running.

How can i handle if client does not have QB S/W.

Comment: Could you please improve your question, it is hard to understand what your goal is and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the traditional QBSDK for accessing your data. However, the first time you connect your application, QB has to be open for it to authenticate your application. During the authentication make sure you select the option to allow for access when QB is not running.

At that point, you can access the QB company file, without the QB UI being open.

William

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a Quickbook [SDK](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/010_qb) that should meet your needs.